# dovecot username reformatting / translation

Tags: authentication, dovecot

I have usernames in the format user@domain.com and my install of dovecot under virtualmin currently expects and works with the format username.domain .

Is it possible to use the settings: **auth_username_translation** and/or **auth_username_format** (or some other method) to enable my clients to still login with the user@domain.com format ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Set `auth_username_format` to

```
%Lu.%Ld
```

It will result username.domain in lowercase.

See [this wiki for](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Variables) complete variables from dovecot